# Find probability given frequency for event

Tags: probability, statistics

Lets say we have three channels with probability of gender based view like this:

chA->men = 0.3
chB->men = 0.7
chC->men = 0.8

In a week sample,a user views total 1000 impressions.
Out of which the views on channels were:
chA= 10
chB= 100
chC=50

Ques: What is the probability that user is a man?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

(10*.3 + 100 * .7 + 50 *.8) / 160 = 113/160 = 70.625 %

that said, there are many unknowns perhaps that can help us model the question better.